# Numbering/sequencing sets of same column values

Tags: excel, duplicates, sequence, countif

How to do numbering/sequencing for sets of same column values? For example:

```
Col1 Col2
Andy  1
Chad  1
Bill  1 
Andy  2
Bill  2
Bill  3
Chad  2
Bill  4
```

Since `Andy` got 2 values, I want to number it 1 and 2 in Column 2. For `Bill`, I want to number it 1, 2, 3 and 4 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `countif` and a sliding range :

```
   A        B
1  val1     =COUNTIF($A$1:A1, A1)
2  valx     =COUNTIF($A$1:A2, A2)
```

and so on.

The formula in column B can be dragged down / autofilled in the column. It anchors to the start of the range and only looks as far down as the value we are numbering; COUNTIF is tallying up the matching values in the preceding set this way.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Such a simple one and I stumbled for hours. I would make myself learn more about this COUNTIF functions then :)

Answer (score 0):

That is kind of slow when your list is really long. I've found sorting the column A to Z or small to larger and then using this formula is much faster:

```
=IF(A2=A1, A1+1,1)
```

Basically 
`if` the value above is the same `then` add one to the count `else` start over at 1