# Numbering/sequencing sets with same column values [R]

Tags: r, count

Exactly the same as this question ([Numbering/sequencing sets of same column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570717/numbering-sequencing-sets-of-same-column-values)) but using R instead of Excel.

How can I create a "count" column to sequentially count the occurrence of a name in a cell, based on its previous occurances.

```
Col1 Col2
Andy  1
Chad  1
Bill  1 
Andy  2
Bill  2
Bill  3
Chad  2
Bill  4
```

I'm using R because my dataset is so large, I cannot use Excel. I've previously used this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1, A1)
```

So, how would I port that to R?

Thanks,

Comment: You could find many dupes for this question in R.  `with(df1, ave(Col1, Col1, FUN = seq_along))` or `dplyr` `df1 %>% group_by(Col1) %>% mutate(Col2 = row_number())`

Comment: Hum thanks for the suggestion. The results were all <NA>

Comment: Not for me based on your example.  Please check the `str(yourdata)`  I assume that you had 'Col1' as `character` class

Comment: Col1 is a factor for me not character. Let me see if it changes when I important without factors.

Comment: Even if it is `factor, the dplyr way should work fine

Comment: `with(df1, ave(seq_along(Col1), Col1, FUN = seq_along))#
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 4` and with `factor`, you get NAs

Comment: Worked! Thank you :)